# How to prevent composer-patches from patching my local path repository?

Tags: composer-php

When I use *cweagans/composer-patches*[¹](https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches) to patch packages that I load from a local path composer repository, the local repository package also gets patched. I have set the symlink option to false, as I suspected that was to blame. The packages are now mirrored, but the packages in the composer repo are still getting patched.

I could "pre-patch" my local packages, but they are copies of external packages that needed some tweaks to the dependencies in their composer.json, so I temporarily copied them to a local repo. Eventually these packages will be updated, and I will be able to just follow along with the updates again.

What do I need to do to prevent my local path composer repo from getting patched?

Comment: disabling symbolic links would have been also my first thought, now thnking what if copying instead of symlinking uses hardlinks? Could you please verify this is (not) the case and also add some more information, e.g. the output of `composer diagnose` which should be the first (err second) step for [troubeshooting composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#general). Interesting question though!

Comment: And could you share if those are dist pacakges or vcs (git?) packages? Asking b/c git  configuration could also interfere with this.

Comment: @hakre: this is a Drupal project, so all packages come from https://packages.drupal.org/8 . No git involved.

Copying really means copying. The patching creates a PATCHES.txt file in the package folder which is also created in the local repo.

Comment: And this Drupal project is not a Composer project? You don't run the `composer` command to install those packages in question? And then you won't let the composer plugin run afterwards from within such a composer invocation? Well then you're right, it has nothing to do with git. However if you're invoking `composer`, and this is what your question suggested to me, it is that Composer itself may involve git(1) for the configured packages. Also take care that not any earlier symbolic link that once was created remained. However if you followed the troubleshooting steps linked, you did already.

Comment: And it may help to better understand the quesiton if you would provide exemplary paths of the both the composer project and the local composer repository of type path, so that the layout becomes more clear as well what it means when you write of what is getting changed (I'd consider any composer repo you mention in your question to be the local one, but I don't know if this is true for all cases nor where it is positioned next to the composer project itself that it references which would help me to get a better understanding).

Comment: And given no hardlinks are involved, is it documented behavior of that composer plugin to not do what is happening in your case? (just asking for clarification, I don't know, so it would be good to know if you know it, otherwise let me know if you don't know either so we're on the same page, thanks!).